# How to change date format from French to US date format?

Tags: datetime, english

I am using [this latex theme](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/bredelediapo/bdxjjgdsgyfr#.V2nJbJMrIY0) for an upcoming presentation.

Everything is good except one thing: the date, which is in French and I want it in US date formatting.

I tried using `\usepackage{datetime}` package and define a custom date format, but I get an error that my custom tag is used outside `\begin{document}`.

I want to access date using `\today` tag. 
Can anyone help me dealing with this?

Answer (score 2):

The US date style can be set with `datetime2` using the package option `en-US`. The abbreviated form can be obtained using `\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{abbr}`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{abbr}

\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\end{document}
```

This produces the date in the form Jun 22, 2016. The full set of options available in `\DTMlangsetup[en-US]` are listed in the "English (US)" section of the [`datetime2-english` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-english/datetime2-english.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the date manually in the line

```
\date{18 Brumaire 2015}
```

use

```
\usepackage[english,calc]{datetime2}
\DTMsavenow{now}% Save current date in 'now'
\date{%
  \DTMfetchday{now} % Retrieve day
  \DTMenglishshortmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{now}} % Retrieve month (in short form)
  \DTMfetchyear{now}}% Retrieve year
```

[image]